# Autologin to programs with USB

Tags: authentication, usb, token

I have found tons of programs that lets you configure a usb to log in to Windows but this is not what i want. 
I have coustomers that don't want to type in long passwords when they use various programs.

Is there any software that configures a flash drive to sign in to specific programs?
Lets say a coustomer inserts his usb and it automatically logs into vpn-client, file zilla, and any other program of your choice that requires a username/password authentication?

Thanks

Comment: For PKI Login to web applications, you may use Signer.Digital browser extension from modern browsers. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked you a company called Yubico and they make a stick called yubikey.
This can do what I need and much more.
They are partnered with Microsoft, Paypal, Facebook, Google and many more.

Incase someone else needs something like this yubikey can be worth looking into, their customer support was also very helpful.